# Powershell script to find line terminator?

Tags: sql, powershell

Can PowerShell "see" line terminators as

`\n`  and `` r`n `` and `0x0a` for example?

When returning the last character of a text file with  line feed terminator I can see using Notepad ++, PowerShell returns the last character as blank, where I would have hoped it could return `\n`

What I'm trying to do is identify files that do not end with a line terminator, as these files break my SQL bulk insert.

Thanks

Comment: This depends on how you're reading the file. If you use something like `Get-Content` you will get back individual lines as pipeline elements, so then you'll see no terminators -- this is by design. If you use `Get-Content -Raw` you'll get back the file as one big string, which you can then split/examine yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell can see line terminators. In order to see them displayed the way you want, you will have to manufacture that output.

```
$hash = @{10 = '\n'; 13 = '\r'}
if ((Get-Content file.txt -Raw) -match '(\r|\n)+\z') {
    ([int[]][char[]]$matches.0).foreach({$hash[$_]})
}
else {
    'No Terminators Found'
}
```

The `Get-Content -Raw` reads a file as a single string. `\r` matches carriage return. `\n` matches line feed. `|` is a regex alternation (an effective OR). `+` matches one or more of the previous match. `\z` is the end of the string (end of file in this case).

`$matches` will automatically contain the matched characters if `-match` operator returns true. Putting it into an `if` statement prevents its `$true` \ `$false` output and allows us to only check `$matches` if a match was successful. `[char[]]` converts the newline characters to an array of `System.Char` so that we can then return an integer array (`[int[]]`) of those `Char` objects. Having an array makes it easier to use the `foreach()` method and run code against each character. Without the array conversion, you'd have a single string of multiple characters from the match results.

The hash table is just a means to display the control characters in the desired format. You could just use `if` or `switch` statements to check instead.

---

By default, `\n` and `\r` control characters are not visible in the PowerShell console. Their byte and hex representations are visible though. Converting the characters to `[char]` and then `[int]` displays their byte representation as an integer. See below:

```
[int][char]"`r"
13
[int][char]"`n"
10
```

You can also utilize `Format-Hex` to see the hex presentation of the file contents.

```
Get-Content file.txt -Raw | Format-Hex

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   6C 69 6E 65 31                                   line1
```

Notice how the ending `0A` (`\n`) and `0D` (`\r`) are missing when a file has no ending newline characters? In contrast, see the same file below with the newline ending characters.

```
Get-Content file.txt -Raw | Format-Hex

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   6C 69 6E 65 31 0D 0A                             line1..
```

You can get all the bytes from `Format-Hex` output by retrieving its `Bytes` property and notice the final `10` and `13` bytes.

```
(Get-Content file.txt -Raw | Format-Hex).Bytes

108
105
110
101
49
13
10
```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks for explaining how PS interprets EOF chars. I completely forgot about using the -Hex switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple test like

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        FileName = $_.FullName
        EndsWithLineTerminator = ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -match '(\r?\n)$'
    }
}
```

Output will look like:

```
FileName                EndsWithLineTerminator
--------                ----------------------
D:\Test\AnotherFile.txt                  False
D:\Test\JustAFile.txt                    False
D:\Test\LF.sql                            True
D:\Test\NoLF.txt                         False
D:\Test\Something.sql                    False
```

If you are interested in files with a certain extension like `.sql` only, add `-Filter '*.sql'` to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.
If you also want to inspect files withoin subfolders, add `-Recurse`

---

If you also want to know **what** terminator is used (CRLF, CR or LF if any) you can extend the above to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $termTest   = ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -match '(\r?\n)$'
    $terminator = if ($termTest) {
        switch ($matches[1]) {
            "`r`n" { 'CRLF'; break }  # Carriage Return + Line Feed
            "`n"   { 'LF'  ; break }  # Line Feed
            "`r"   { 'CR' }           # Carriage Return
        }
    }
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        FileName               = $_.FullName
        EndsWithLineTerminator = $termTest
        TerminatorUsed         = $terminator
    }
}
```

showing something like

```
FileName                EndsWithLineTerminator TerminatorUsed
--------                ---------------------- --------------
D:\Test\AnotherFile.txt                  False               
D:\Test\JustAFile.txt                    False               
D:\Test\LF.sql                            True CRLF          
D:\Test\NoLF.txt                         False               
D:\Test\Something.sql                    False
```

Comment: A script easier than this to achieve what I wanted to would be hard to come by. Thanks.